# WPF Border ZIndex not working as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml, border, overlay, z-index

I have the following problem:  I overlay 2 controls over one another and want a single border to surround them both.  I thought I could control the ZIndex of the border over each control and give them a low ZIndex: 2.  Then give the  controls a higher ZIndex (4 and 5).  The following xaml as a UserControl is what I'm referring to:

```
    <Canvas>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="30">
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="20"  Fill="Aqua" Canvas.ZIndex="5"/>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="00">
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="200" Fill="Yellow" Canvas.ZIndex="5"/>
     </Border>
</Canvas>
```

The result looks like:

[image]

But I desire is the following image but with the border with red-X removed:

[image]

Can anyone recommend a way to do this ?  The Border ZIndex method is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ZIndex` is not working cause `Rectangles` are not childs of `Canvas`. So you can fix it by placing them outside of borders and adjusting its `Heights`, `Widths` and `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top` properties. So the example looks like this.

```
<Canvas>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" Canvas.ZIndex="2" 
            Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="26"
            Width="208" Height="28">
    </Border>
    <Rectangle Width="200" Height="20"  Fill="Aqua" Canvas.ZIndex="5"
               Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="30" />
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" Height="208" Width="58" BorderThickness="4" 
            Canvas.ZIndex="2" Canvas.Left="146" Canvas.Top="00">
    </Border>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="4" Width="50" Height="200" Fill="Yellow" 
               Canvas.ZIndex="5"/>
</Canvas>
```